# $h=16 \cos\left(\frac{d}{500}\right)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The two questions I need to answer are based on this formula where h is number of hours and d is number of days.  $$h=16*
\cos\left(\frac{d}{500}\right)$$

I need to find the hours of daylight on Sept 24, the 267th day of the year.  I also need to state the period.  Part one is easy $$h=16\cos\left(\frac{267}{500}\right)$$ $$h=13.77\text{ hours}$$

Part two not so straight forward.  The book says a period can be modeled as $f(x)= f(x+P)$ I thought one day would be one period.  But it turns out something like $1,000 \pi = Period$

That would make sense if this is true $\frac{1,000 \pi}{500}$ The book also says for the cos function $2\pi = Period$.

Does this make sense?  How would I write the function?  What is the 1,000?  Would that be days?

Comment: In your case $d$ is $x$ so  $\cos \frac{d}{500} = \cos (\frac{d}{500}+2\pi)= \cos \frac{d+1000\pi}{500}$. Thus, the period is $1000\pi$ days.

Comment: Thanks.  I see it now.  I think it might be $cos(d + \frac{1,000 \pi}{500})$.  Imaybe saying the same as you but I now know how to write the function.